# FooterRow Summary Value is not changing on Filtering records in Jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a function which will calculate summary of particular column and load it into footer of the grid .Here is the code..

```
$(function () {
            var gridData = null;
            var nn = null;

            grid = $("#gridId"),
            calculateTotal = function () {
                var gridData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
                i = 0, totalAmount = 0, totalduration = 0;

                for (; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                    var rowData = gridData[i];
                    totalAmount += Number(rowData.price);
                    totalduration += Number(rowData.duration);
                }
                grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { name: "TOTAL", duration: totalduration, price: totalAmount });
            };
        });
```

Now Here I am calling this summary function ...

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'Default.aspx/MyMethod',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (ReportDataNew, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                //debugger;
                gridData = JSON.parse(ReportDataNew.d);
                console.log(gridData);
                //alert(gridData.length);

                $("#gridId").jqGrid({
                    data: gridData,
                    datatype: "local",
                    height: '100%',
                    autowidth: true,
                    ignoreCase: true,
                    rowNum: 50,
                    rowList: [50, 100, 200],
                    colNames: ['UserName',  'Duration', 'Destination', 'Price'],
                    colModel: [
                            { name: 'username', index: 'username', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'destination', index: 'destination', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                            { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center', formatter: 'currency' }

                        ],
                    pager: '#gridpager',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    toppager: true,
                    loadtext: 'Loading...',
                    footerrow: true,
                    userDataOnFooter: true,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        calculateTotal();
                    }


                });
```

But the summary values at the footer row remains same on filtering the records from the filter toolbar ...
I need updated summary values at the footer on filtering from filter toolbar or after searching...

Any help will be highly appreciated/.
Thnx in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')` to calculate the value of the footer row (summary row). It's practical if you need access to *all local data from all pages independent from the filter used*. If you need calculate summary from the currently displayed page of data (and with the filter applied) you should use `grid.jqGrid('getRowData')` instead.

Comment: Thanx sir for ur response...i changed in my function var gridData = grid.jqGrid( 'getRowData') but it is calculating only that page summary .and filter is also not working

Comment: @Ram: It seems that you have very special requirements. To access *all filtered data over the pages* you can use the approach which I described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935).

Comment: summary is coming for the current page data whereas i need summary from all pages in the footer after filtering

Comment: Thanx sir for ur response ..Sir i want summary in the footer to get changed on filtering records of the grid...This is my requiremnt.

Comment: @Ram: look in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935) which I referenced before. If allows you to access *filtered* part of `data` parameter (filtered corresponds to the last filter applied). You should be able to solve you problem using the approach.