# scroll to jqgrid item by id/key

Tags: jqgrid

I've a jqgrid width multiple pages. Every row has an unique id. Is there a function to scroll directly i.e. to row id `1234`?

```
var mygrid = $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'get_sql_json.php',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [100, 200, 500],
    autoencode: true,
    autowidth: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    shrinkToFit: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I find your question very interesting, so I prepared [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectRowOnUnknownPage.htm) which demonstrates the corresponding solution.

[image]

One can choose the row in the dropdown-box and click the button "Select row by id". The specified row will be selected with `setSelection` method if it is on the current page. If the row in on another page then it will be calculated new page number and the grid will be reloaded with the specified row pre-selected. I use `current: true` option of `reloadGrid` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935).

It's important that you use `loadonce: true` which allows to save more as one page of rows. In the case the grid works like the grid having `datatype: "local"` with `data` parameter defined with the data returned from the server at the first load.

For the implementation of the selection I use the approach described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935). I overwrite (subclass) the `select` method of internal `$.jgrid.from` method used by jqGrid so that the last *full* sorted and filtered local data are saved in new internal variable lastSelected. It allows to access the full dataset instead of the current page only (the contains the data from [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L1758) instead of the current page only after execution of `slice` from [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L1764)).

The most important part of the code of the demo is below:

```js
var mydata = [ ... ],
    $grid = $("#list"),
    oldFrom = $.jgrid.from,
    lastSelected, i, n, $ids, id;

// "subclass" $.jgrid.from method and save the last
// select results in lastSelected variable
$.jgrid.from = function (source, initalQuery) {
    var result = oldFrom.call(this, source, initalQuery),
        old_select = result.select;
    result.select = function (f) {
        lastSelected = old_select.call(this, f);
        return lastSelected;
    };
    return result;
};

// create the grid
$grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    ...
    loadComplete: function () {
        this.p.lastSelected = lastSelected; // set this.p.lastSelected
    }
});

...
// fill select with all ids from the data
$ids = $("#selectedId");
for (i = 0, n = mydata.length; i < n; i++) {
    id = mydata[i].id;
    $("<option>").val(id).text(id).appendTo($ids);
}

$("#selectId").button().click(function () {
    var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelected"), j, l,
        idName = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "localReader").id,
        idToSelect = $("#selectedId").val(),
        rows = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "rowNum"),
        currentPage = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "page"),
        newPage;
    if (filteredData) {
        for (j = 0, l = filteredData.length; j < l; j++) {
            if (String(filteredData[j][idName]) === idToSelect) {
                // j is the 0-based index of the item
                newPage = Math.floor(j / rows) + 1;
                if (newPage === currentPage) {
                    $grid.jqGrid("setSelection", idToSelect);
                } else {
                    // set selrow or selarrrow
                    if ($grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "multiselect")) {
                        $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
                            page: newPage,
                            selrow: idToSelect,
                            selarrrow: [idToSelect]
                        });
                    } else {
                        $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
                            page: newPage,
                            selrow: idToSelect
                        });
                    }
                    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (j >= l) {
            $grid.jqGrid("resetSelection");
            alert("The id=" + idToSelect + " can't be seen beacuse of the current filter.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oleg I found your answer very interesting as well. I wonder if this will work in a tree grid too?  Specially when the row I want to scroll to is somewhere deep down the nesting and not open (collapsed node). Can is expand the node and parent node too so that row is clearly visible?

Comment: @Ali: こんにちは. The current answer was created for the grid with *multiple pages*. Selection of row on another page is not possible directly, so I demonstrated here the trick how to detect the page with required row, reload the grid to the page and select the row finally. TreeGrid can be on **one page** only. So the implementation will be absolutely another. Nevertheless it's possible to implement.

Comment: おはようございます　オレぐ様　(Good morning Oregu Sama). A pleasant surprise to see Japanese in your answer. I will post a new question for that purpose because I guess if you can spare time to answer, that will be helpful for many others too.

Comment: I have posted a new [treegrid related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521226/jqgrid-treegrid-scroll-to-a-row-by-row-id-and-expand-the-node-if-collapsed) based on the comments. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an ID using `setSelection` to scroll to that row, but only if it is on the current page.