# Jqgrid treegrid scroll to a row by row ID and expand the node if collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

Scenario is a Jqgrid treegrid with all nodes loaded, some of them collapsed some of them expanded as a result of user interaction. 
Now there is a need to scroll to a specific row based on the row ID, and if the row is inside a collapsed node, then expand the node till row is visible to the user.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand the nodes of the TreeGrid you can use `expandRow`. One should additionally make a loop and expand all parents of the row. One can use `getNodeParent` to get direct parent. Additionally one should use `scrollrows: true` option to scroll the grid to selected row.

[The resulting demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandRowSelectWithScroll.htm) allows to choose the row by rowid which need be selected. Clicking on "Select row by id" button do what you need:

[image]

Click event handle which I used in the demo you will see below

```js
$("#selectId").button().click(function () {
    var idToSelect = $("#selectedId").val(), // id of the row which need be selected
        localRowData = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", idToSelect);

    while (localRowData.parent !== null && localRowData.parent.toUpperCase() !== "NULL") {
        localRowData = $grid.jqGrid("getNodeParent", localRowData);
        $grid.jqGrid("expandRow", localRowData);
    }

    // we use scrollrows: true option so the selection below
    // will scroll the grid to the selected row additionally
    $grid.jqGrid("setSelection", idToSelect);
});
```