# How can I get only the viewable data (eg the one returned from a search) in jqgrid to use in highchart

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to get the data that is viewable on the grid, like for example after a search. I thought of getting it from the html document and looping through the records but this does not cover the case of multiple pages on the grid and the only other alternative I have is

$('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');

but that returns the whole data and not just the filtered one.

The main purpose of this is to have the data that is currently visible on the jqgrid to be used in a highchart.

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: How it is related with highcharts?

Comment: I didn't mention that in order to display the data I would move it on a hidden table and then read it from the highchart code to display it and was also hopping that there might be another way to do all that instead of my way. But then I just though that I shouldn't make the question too confusing and left it out.

Comment: Not sure if you are still trying to do this but looks like the answer to this question would point you in the right direction:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775115/get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid