# jqgrid - get all ids of all pages not just current page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to get ids of all pages in not `datatype:'local'` or having `loadonce:true` ?
Because `$grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow')` gives `ids` of the current page. I need the ids of all pages. I have searched a lot but didn't find a soloution for that.
Any idea?

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/2567813

Comment: @CJ Ramki I don't have local data