# how to export all jqgrid data which should have only visible columns irrespective of paging

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, export, free-jqgrid

I want to know whether there is any method to get all jqGrid data of visible columns irrespective of paging.

```
$("#listTableSupply").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
```

But it shows all json data which I have passed to jqgrid. As I use paging in jqgrid if I use

```
$('#list').jqGrid('getRowData');
```

I get only the records from 1st Page.

I need to know is there any way that I have to get all data with visible columns irrespective of paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `getGridParam` with `data` is the correct way. If you need to remove some properties from the item or the array then you should make deep copy of the array (by usage of `$.extend(true, {}, data)`) and remove unneeded properties from every item of the array.

Alternatively you can copy all properties with non-hidden columns in new array. The code could be about the following:

```
// get the reference to all parameters of the grid
var p = $("#listTableSupply").jqGrid("getGridParam");

// save the list of all non-hidden columns as properties of helper object
var colNames = {}, i, cm;
for (i = 0; i < p.colModel.length; i++) {
    cm = p.colModel[i];
    if (cm.hidden !== true) {
        colNames[cm.name] = true;
    }
}
// We have now colNames object with properties,
// which correspond to non-hidden columns of the grid

// Make copy of p.data including only non-hidden columns
var newData = new Array(p.data.length), prop, newItem, item;
for (i = 0; i < p.data.length; i++) {
    item = p.data[i];
    newItem = {};
    for (prop in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && colNames[prop]) {
            // fill only properties of non-hidden columns
            newItem[prop] = item[prop];
        }
    }
    newData[i] = newItem;
}
```

I don't tested the above code, but I hope it fill `newData` array with the data, which you need.

**UPDATED:** I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData1.htm) for you, which demonstrates the usage of `lastSelectedData` instead of `data`. It fills in the resulting array `newData` the filtered items of the grid, including only visible columns. You can filter the data and then click on the button "Show non-hidden fields of filtered and sorted data". The demo fills the `newData` array and display it. I used the following code inside of `click` handler:

```
var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"), filteredData = p.lastSelectedData,
    idName = p.localReader.id, i, cm, prop, newItem, item,
    colNames = {}, newData;
if (p.lastSelectedData.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < p.colModel.length; i++) {
        cm = p.colModel[i];
        if (cm.hidden !== true && $.inArray(cm.name, ["rn", "cb", "subgrid"]) < 0) {
            colNames[cm.name] = true;
        }
    }
    colNames[idName] = true;
    newData = new Array(p.lastSelectedData.length);
    for (i = 0; i < p.lastSelectedData.length; i++) {
        item = p.lastSelectedData[i];
        newItem = {};
        for (prop in item) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && colNames[prop]) {
                // fill only properties of non-hidden columns
                newItem[prop] = item[prop];
            }
        }
        newData[i] = newItem;
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(newData));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Will it work when I filter my data in jqgrid. As I need to show only filter data if any filtering is done

Comment: @user1268130: You are welcome! If you need to use filtered data instead of full data then you should get the data from `lastSelectedData` instead of `data` (see [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31568275/315935) and [this old one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935))

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Will check it out now. :)

Comment: The newdata is providing all the columns, where I need only visible columns.by the way it should be p.data.length

Comment: @user1268130: I created the demo, which demonstrates what you need. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.