# Is it possible to get all jqGrid rows, across multiple pages, in the currently sorted order?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm using the latest version of jqGrid (v4.7.1). I have a grid which is populated with local data and has multiple pages of data. The user has sorted the data client-side. I would now like to retrieve **all** rows in their sorted order. Is it possible to do this?

Here's what I know:

```
var data = this.ui.grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

This statement returns **all** rows in the grid, but returns them in their initial state. It is not affected by any sorting operation.

```
var rowData = this.ui.grid.jqGrid('getRowData');
```

This statement returns all rows in **the current page**, but does return them in the properly sorted order.

I was thinking about taking all the data and running it through the grid's sorting function, but that function is heavily guarded. I can get access to it by calling something like:

```
var data = this.ui.grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
$.jgrid.from([])._doSort(data, 0)
```

However, this code still throws errors as jqGrid expects some other properties to have been set before calling _doSort. I'm confident I can get this working, but it feels like I'm hacking at some code in a really unintended fashion.

What are my options?

EDIT: This works, but it's pretty hacky:

```
var rowNum = this.ui.grid.getGridParam('rowNum');
this.ui.grid.setGridParam({ rowNum: 10000 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
var data = this.ui.grid.getRowData();
this.ui.grid.setGridParam({ rowNum: rowNum }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `$.jgrid.from` sill be used internally by jqGrid. The usage of of the methods is not documented. In general one should first *create* an object using `$.jgrid.from`: for example one can use

```
var data = $("#mygrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
var query = $.jgrid.from(data);
```

Then one should set some internal properties of the object, for example, make the later queries case insensitive

```
query = query.ignoreCase();
```

Then one can sort or filter the data. For sorting one should use

```
query.orderBy("columnNameByWhichOneSort",
    "a", // or "d" for "desc" sorting
    stype,  // sorttype from colModel oder "text"
    srcfmt, // typically ""
    sfunc); // typically null
```

To get the final results one should use

```
var queryResults = query.select();
```

I recommend you to set some breakpoints inside of [addLocalData](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L1713) and to debug the code. If you click on come column header the grid will be sorted you you will see how `addLocalData` uses `$.jgrid.from` internally.

Probably you can just to follow [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935) instead and "subclass" `$.jgrid.from`. As the result you can get full results (all pages) based on the sorting and searching criteria of the user.

**UPDATED**: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) provides `lastSelectedData` option. See [the demo](https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) in [the list of demos](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/README.md#some-demos-which-demonstrates-new-features).

Comment: Thanks oleg! Any thoughts on jqGrid having a method out-of-the-box which returns all rows w/ proper sorting instead of having to dig for it? It seems like it has been a common issue for several years.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: I think so too. As you probably knows there are some forks of jqGrid after changing of license agreements. I've implemented already some new features (see [the post](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/issues/1#issuecomment-69001575) for the base information about one new feature) and have fixed many bugs of jqGrid 4.7 in [my fork](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid). I will include the suggestion in my TODO list. I will inform you after I have the feature implemented.

Comment: Excellent! You'll be happy to know a lot of developers over here in our team are stoked to hear that ;) :D Good luck and looking forward to it.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: The implementation was very simple and I did this already. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) and the corresponding code [changes](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/f1d51b32338863007e1d0c7bd3f8281bc881787e) in my jqGrid fork. So the first version of my fork (which I plan soon) will already have the feature. You can anytime download my current development state from [github](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid) and use just `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`, `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.map`.