# JqGrid 'lastSelected' parameter undefined in jqGrid 4.8.2 while trying to retrieve filtered results

Tags: jqgrid

I was looking to fetch the client side filtered data from the jqgrid. I saw this 
[Get all rows not filtered from jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775115/get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid)
post and tried Oleg's solution. But i am getting  an Undefined error for 'lastSelected' parameter. I am using jqGrid 4.8.2 and jQuery 1.10.2. It looks in this version the lastSelected parameter has been renamed or removed. I have to use these versions because of some other code dependencies. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide sample code so we can replicate the issue and have a reference in case the link stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short time after publishing of jqGrid 4.7 at [Dec 8, 2014](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/v4.7.0) Tony Tomov have changed license agreement (see jqGrid 4.7 published at [Dec 16, 2014](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/v4.7.1)). Because of that I started so continue to develop my own fork of jqGrid based on jqGrid 4.7 (the last version available under MIT/GPLv2 licenses) under the name **free jqGrid**. You can download it from [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). More information about it is available in [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and in [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

So there are exist now Guriddo jqGrid JS which can be purchase [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). So the full name of jqGrid 4.8.2 is Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.8.2.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935) which you referenced shows how to "subclass" internal jqGrid method `$.jgrid.from` to have access to new custom "lastSelected" parameter. The technique is tricky, but it works with *old versions of jqGrid*.

**If you would use free jqGrid 4.8 or later then you can just use new `lastSelectedData` option**, which have the same meaning like "lastSelected" parameter in [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935). [At the end of readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#some-demos-which-demonstrates-new-features) you will find some demos. **[The first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) is what you need.**

Comment: Thanks you so much for the response @Oleg . I tried the solution. Now i don't get the undefined error but still i cannot get the job done.  When i debug i see the the 'filteredData' parameter is returning null. I am using the data from server and load once is set to true. So like you suggested in the thread i used '_id_ ' instead of id  but i still cannot get the result. Also i have subgrids in my grid. Unfortunately I cannot post my code here, because it says it is too long. Is there a way i can send you the code?

Comment: @Neelima: Please reread my answer. The name of parameter is `lastSelectedData` and not `filteredData`. You can open [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm), click on right mouse button to open context menu and choose "Souce Code" to view  the code of the demo. You will see that I use `var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelectedData");`. If you use [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GetFilteredData.htm) for old jqGrid and subclass `$.jgrid.from` then the name of the parameter: `lastSelected` (not `filteredData`).

Comment: @Neelima: If you open [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg?tab=profile) on the stackoverflow you fill find my email: oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com