# Jqgrid afterSearch data - how to get it

Tags: filter, jqgrid

I need to get only the data that is a result of the search as opposed to the entire set.

This code gives me the entire set:

```
 var data = $("#my-grid").getGridParam("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer on your question depends on which fork of jqGrid and which version you use. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (4.8/4.9) then use `lastSelectedData` parameter instead of `data`. You will get the subset of filtered and sorted data (all data, not just the current page!!!). See [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/README.md#the-following-new-jqgrid-options-are-implemented-comparing-with-jqgrid-47) and [the first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) at [the end of readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/README.md#some-demos-which-demonstrates-new-features).

If you have to use old jqGrid versions then you can follow [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935) which shows how one can subclass internal method `$.jgrid.from` to be able to save the results of the last `select` over the local data.