# Jqgrid - How to perform search locally for entire data set,without considering the pagination

Tags: search, jqgrid

Jqgrid -Search functionality - 
How to perform search locally for entire data set,without considering the pagination.

I have nearly 1500 records in my database and jqgrid has pagination .
So if I search for something,it should perform search with entire dataset irrespective of the page in the grid and it should not request database everytime ,it should be loaded only once.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, then you should use `lastSelectedData` option, which returns, in contrast to `data`, *filtered* and *sorted* data items from **all page**s of jqGrid. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) demonstrates the usage of `lastSelectedData`. It's important that the option exist in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork only (the fork, which I develop). If you have to use an old jqGrid version then you can follow [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935), which describes more tricky alternative.