# Is there a way to get all the data from the grid that is sorted and edited in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that can be paging, sorted, and edited.
I have to save data after I get all the data in the grid.

For example, if you sorted and edited a grid, you must be able to import the edited and sorted data, that is, the data displayed on the screen.

I used this method.

```
$('#grid).jqGrid('getRowData')
```

It can get edited grid data, but it only takes one page of data.

so I used this method.

```
$('#grid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data)
```

It can get all grid data, but it's not apply sorting.

I tried this answer.
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775115/get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid/9831125#9831125)
It can get sorting data, but it's not apply inline edit.

I want to get all the grid data.
Is there any way?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov I use 5.0.1. I can't change a version. Because I'm using this version for the project. Is there a way in the latest version?

Comment: Yes in the latest versions there is a method, which do exactly what you want,

Comment: @TonyTomov Thank you. It's too bad I couldn't use it ... :(  If you can tell me what version it is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's very simple. :(
Just add {key: true} in colModel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).